# Where can one find an up-to-date list of all accepted Scrabble words

Tags: scrabble

I would like a list of all up to date Scrabble words. Where can I find one in list form please? I have tried Tile Fish and also Collins.

Comment: You can find the official scrabble dictionary on the Hasbro website, though it is not in list form. https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/tools

Comment: Merriam-Webster offer several lists on their website.
Lists such as Starting with..., Ending with..., 2-letter word, 3-letter words, words containing J, or Q, or X, or Z, etc.
https://scrabble.merriam.com/word-lists

Comment: The complete list is available for purchase to NASPA members:https://www.scrabbleplayers.org/cgi-bin/shop.pl

Answer (score 1):

According to [scrabblepages.com](https://www.scrabblepages.com/scrabble/rules/)"Any word that is found in a standard English dictionary can be used in the game of Scrabble. There are also Official Scrabble Dictionaries that can be purchased for more word options.

There are some words that are not allowed to be played and these include suffixes, prefixes and abbreviations. Any word that requires the use of a hyphen or apostrophe cannot be played in the game. Any word that required the use of a capital letter is not allowed.

When playing an English version of the game, foreign words are not allowed to be placed on the board. However, if the foreign word does appear in a standard English dictionary, it is allowed. The reason for this is due to the fact that the word is spoken enough and is considered part of the English language."

Now that being said there are words that are definitely not child or teen appropriate under that category and house rules are always fun to use.